# How to use capitalized initials in testdox names?

Tags: php, phpunit

I like the way PHPUnit automatically breaks up my test names by convention.

```
public function testValidDataInput()
```

When I run with testdox flag:

```
phpunit --testdox tests
```

Becomes:

> ```
> PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> MyClass
>  [x] Valid data input
> ```

But I couldn't find in [the documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html) how to work around capitalized initials.

```
public function testValidURLInput()
```

Becomes:

> ```
> MyClass
>  [x] Valid u r l input
> ```

Is it possible to get it to display like:

> ```
> MyClass
>  [x] Valid URL input
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `testValidUrlInput()` (which is not really a good name, especially when you want to use TestDox output) to get `valid url input` or you can annotate your test method with `@testdox Valid URL input` to get `Valid URL input`.

Comment: `@testdox` is perfect, thanks! still getting started with PHPUnit, so why is `testValidUrlInput` not a good name? Can you suggest a more appropriate one?

Comment: Because "valid url input" is not a complete sentence.

Comment: I see, so does "Validate URL input" jive well?